# tastypie multiple row insert in table

Tags: python, django, tastypie

django,tastypie  i have hire_users_skills and i am passing on json formate data with POST method . so want to insert in multiple row with on that table .

EX :-

```
{
  "skill_id": "451,56,78",
  "user_id": 344
}
```

in table i want to isert like this

[image]

my Resource code is

```
class HireUsersSkills(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    skill_id = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'hire_users_skills'
```